# Highmaps: what is the code for a county?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I am new to Highmaps and am playing with it.

I notice that it uses the following data for a county in Maryland, USA.

```
Object { key="us-md-025",  value=23}]
```

I am curious about "025". What is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is called the "fips" or "county fips" code. It is a unique identifier for that particular county in the state you look at. Here is a good intro:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_county_code

A full county code looks like `23025` where the first two characters are the state fips code and the last three are the county fips code. Depending on the data set you are looking at you can also view the areatype code (for things like Metro Area, County, State, US Region, etc).

Full list of county fips codes can be found here:
http://www.census.gov/2010census/xls/fips_codes_website.xls

Answer (score 2):

Map documentation can be found at...

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection

Map data can be found at...

http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/

If you scroll down to "USA States" > "Maryland, admin2" > "GeoJSON" link, you can open/download the map data for Maryland. Search the JSON data for "us-md-025". You will find "name":"Harford".

Comment: Hi Bobby, thanks for chiming in! I went to these two pages before. I was able to seen the data you mentioned. My question is what 025 is. Is it a ISO code or something? What is the name/title for "025"? Take postal code as example. We know 20850 is a postal code. So what is "025"? Best.

Comment: On the documentation page, there is a "Map Properties" section that discusses this. The "hc-key" property is an unique hierarchical identifier consisting of "-" separated ids used to drill down to the given map area. The first id is normally a two letter ISO-3166 country code (e.g. "us" for USA). For the USA maps, the second id might be a state code (e.g. "md" for Maryland) and the third might be a FIPS county code (eg. "025" for Hardford).